# Change Laravel Session Driver from Cookie to Database

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

I would like to change the Laravel Session Driver. The application is already up and running.  There is a helper class with getters and setters and modifiers that accesses the session.

#### My question

How do I change the driver from cookie to database? What is the correct procedure to change the session driver from cookie to database?

Comment: So the currently authenticated users have to stay logged in? What is your reason for changing it to database based?

Comment: @MaartenDev Good question! The shopping cart is currently saved in the session. However, a new feature is to be built in, with which the admin can display all current shopping baskets. And they can also filter them by date, etc.

Comment: Is it required to keep the shopping cart content when migrating to the database driver?

Comment: no it is not required

Comment: Changing it should be quite easy: 1. generate table: `php artisan session:table` 2. migrate: `php artisan migrate` 3. set `SESSION_DRIVER` in `.env` to `database`. checkout the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#database

Comment: Thanks @MartenDev. So only change the config and not the code. that sounds very good.

Comment: Yep, you can then query the table in the database to retrieve session data

Answer (score 1):

According to question comments you have to follow the steps in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#database), then change the `SESSION_DRIVER` in `.env` file to the `database`